# why applying negative margin right doesn't work?

Tags: css

My Code:

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: red;
}

/* this is inside the container */
.inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC8Gi.png)

[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGdiN.png)

What am I doing wrong? I've seen Bootstrap grid do something similar to this.


**Quick update. sorry for poor explaining.further explaition:

 margin: 0 -10px; is used to add margin to left and right but the right side doesn't do anything.**

Comment: that is not `margin-right`, that is `margin-right and left`. The syntax is in your case `margin:[top/bottom][right/left]`

Answer (score 5):

For `.inside`, `width: 100%` only covers the space inside the padding of the `.container`. You need to add the extra 20px back to its width:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: red;
}


/* this is inside the container */

.inside {
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='inside'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just set the width to "auto".

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the CSS `margin` property is:

```
margin: (all|vertical horizontal|top right bottom left)(unit);
```

That means that your declaration of

```
margin: 0 -10px;
```

is using the `vertical horizontal` syntax - i.e. you're applying `-10px` margin to *both* sides of the element, not just the right. To fix this, use the full syntax:

```
margin: 0 -10px 0 0;
```

Comment: I was about to vote up when I saw the author of the answer, which terrified me into doing nothing at last.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to set the right margin:

```
margin:0 -10px 0 0;
    // top, right, bottom, left
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having similar issues...what worked for me was to change the width of the container to auto instead of 100%.  100% width + negtive margin right margins seem to cause issues.